# Two-level join Sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three Model classes, representing three tables in my PostgreSQL database: Project, Label, ProjectLabel. Many projects can have multiple labels:

```py
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    labels = db.relationship('ProjectLabel')

class Label(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'labels'

    label_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    label_name = db.Column(db.String())

class ProjectLabel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'projects_labels'

    projectlabel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    projectlabel_projectid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'))
    projectlabel_labelid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('labels.label_id'))
```

How can I query Project model, so that I can get objects from `labels` table?

Specifically, how can I get `label_name` of the label assigned to the Project? I somehow need to connect between Project(`labels`) -> ProjectLabel -> Label classes

Comment: you need the sql query for getting project name correct? in that case a query of type `select labels.name from labels left join projects_labels on projects_labels.projectlabel_labelid= labels.label_label_id left join projects on  projects.id=projects_labels.projectlabel_projectid where projects.id =<enter your project id>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the related labels in long form:

```
db.session.query(Project.id,
                 Label.label_name)\
          .filter(ProjectLabel.projectlabel_projectid==Project.id)\
          .filter(Label.label_id==ProjectLabel.projectlabel_labelid)\
          .order_by(Project.id.asc()).all()
```

If you want the labels in comma-delimited lists use `func.group_concat()`:

```
db.session.query(Project.id,
                 func.group_concat(Label.label_name).label('related_labels'))\
          .filter(ProjectLabel.projectlabel_projectid==Project.id)\
          .filter(Label.label_id==ProjectLabel.projectlabel_labelid)\
          .group_by(Project.id)\
          .order_by(Project.id.asc()).all()
```